# Modular arithmetic multiplication table exam question

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I am stuck on this past paper question, and looking at the solution didn't seem to give me any hints either. I'm stuck on part b but I'll write the first part out anyways.

Let $K =\mathbb Z_2$. Let $f$ be an element of $\mathbb K[X]$ be the polynomial $X^2 + 1$.

a. Show that $f$ is a reducible element of $\mathbb K[X]$.
b. Let $M$ be the ring you get by working "modulo $f$". Let $a = [X]$, so $M = \{0,1,a,a+1\}$. Write out the multiplication table of $M$.

I got the multiplication parts of 1 and 0 right, but I'm stuck with the significance of a and a+1 in regards to the table.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For problem a, note that $f(x) = (x+1)^2$.

For problem b, simply compute. Your professor is using $a$ to represent the equivalence class of $x$, which is a little confusing. Let's just use $x$ and then call it $a$ when all is said and done. In the quotient ring,

- $x^2 = 1$ (since $x^2 + 1 = 0$ and $1 = -1$).
- $x(x+1) = x^2 + x = x + 1$ (see above)
- $(x+1)^2 = 0$

That finishes your multiplication table (change $x$s back to $a$s).

Comment: Brilliant answer - thanks a lot!

Comment: If you loved the answer upvote it, @user3052576...and later, eventually, accept this (or any other) answer. +1

Comment: I would upvote but it seems I need to build my reputation first. Also i've accepted this answer. Many thanks once again!